# OneSignal onReceived listener action when app is in background

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, onesignal

I want to store the notification data when I receive the notification. This works fine when app is open, but if the app is in background, onReceived doesn't get triggered because componentWillUnmount removes the listener.

This is what I have right now.

```
componentWillMount() {

  OneSignal.addEventListener('received', this.onReceived);
  OneSignal.addEventListener('opened', this.onOpened);
  OneSignal.addEventListener('ids', this.onIds);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    OneSignal.removeEventListener('received', this.onReceived);
    OneSignal.removeEventListener('opened', this.onOpened);
    OneSignal.removeEventListener('ids', this.onIds);
}

onReceived = (notification) => this.props.dispatch(
  addNotification({"id": notification.payload.notificationID, "text": notification.payload.body, "url": notification.payload.additionalData.somedata})
)
```

Any suggestion how I can make this work when the app is in background?

Comment: Did you find any solution?